# Python Flask within Spyder - Code Updates not being Reflected

Tags: python, flask, spyder

I am developing a Python Flask application within Spyder however, whenever I save code, the changes are not being reflected in the browser. For instance, if I change < print "Hello World" > to < print "Hello World 123" >, the changes are not being reflected when I save the code and refresh the browser.

Have any of you experienced this issue in the past and know how to resolve? Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks!

RESOLVED:
I figured it out, thanks for your direction!

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD']=True
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = "127.0.0.1:5002"         
    app.run()
```

Comment: Does setting configuration value `TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD = True` help?

Comment: I ran the code again using that config value but it did seem to work when I re-ran --> app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True